# Django complex filter: Time out to put the end of the list, and ordering one that has the lowest time at the beginning?

Tags: python, django, filter, django-queryset

Samples have time to stand in the refrigerator
and as time will eventually have to go looking and turning the samples, so far ok.

In this case the result below appears with the shortest time until the timeout has.

```
amostras =  Amostra.objects.order_by('data_fim')
```

But I do not want that.
I want to run out the time he goes back on the list and what is less time to get ahead in the list.

amostra4 - 13/Jan/2014 15:51:44 => less time

amostra5 - 13/Jan/2014 16:51:44 => the rest of the list in sequence of time

amostra6 - 13/Jan/2014 16:51:44 => the rest of the list in sequence of time

amostra3 - 13/Jan/2014 14:51:44 => timeout

amostra2 - 13/Jan/2014 14:51:44 => timeout

amostra1 - 13/Jan/2014 14:51:44 => timeout

Comment: its not very clear what your asking .,.. but if you have a whole lot of timestamps you probably want to paginate it.. timeouts are part of the web architecture not django ...

Comment: Excuse and my first question on this site.
Yes, right after he has paging.

Comment: use paging in your query `amostras =  Amostra.objects.order_by('data_fim')[0:100]` would be page 1 `amostras =  Amostra.objects.order_by('data_fim')[100:200]` would be page 2

Comment: :( But not and so I'm thinking. edited the question, I think I will understand better.

Comment: I can't understand what you are asking. Do you just want the reverse of the order you have now?

Comment: what type of field is `data_fim` and what value do you store for timeout?

Comment: It is a datetime, not automatic and field =>  datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 13, 20, 58, 40, 75934, tzinfo=<UTC>)

Comment: `Amostra.objects.filter('data_fim >"=some_time).order_by('data_fim').all()` is that what you want?

Comment: `timezone_agora =  timezone.now()
amostras =  Amostra.objects.filter('data_fim' >= timezone_agora).order_by('data_fim').all()` Error @JoranBeasley: Exception Value: 
can't compare datetime.datetime to str

Comment: `timezone_agora = datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 13, 21, 46, 6, 152431, tzinfo=<UTC>) amostras__data_fim = datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 12, 3, 20, 38, tzinfo=<UTC>)`

Comment: Not the reason for the error. Being that the two objects are the same.

Comment: I tried that here, but it removes them as timeout, in which they will have to go to the end of the list. `Amostra.objects.filter(data_fim__gte=timezone_agora).order_by('-data_fim')` Other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved as follows:

```
#postgresql
amostras =  Amostra.objects.extra(select={'controle':'(case when data_fim < current_timestamp then 2 else 1 end)'},order_by=['controle','data_fim'])

#mysql
amostras =  Amostra.objects.extra(select={'controle':'(case when data_fim < now() then 2 else 1 end)'},order_by=['controle','data_fim'])

#sqlite
amostras =  Amostra.objects.extra(select={'controle':"(case when data_fim < datetime('now') then 2 else 1 end)"},order_by=['controle','data_fim'])
```